# EmberJS pre 2 used to pass in the JS event object for actions

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

```
# in the handlebars template    
{{action "do_something" target="view"}}

# in the view
APP.view = Ember.View.extend(
  do_something: (evt) ->
    console.log evt #this used to contain a javascript event object, it was useful at times :(
)
```

I know I can pass in a context. But I want to know if there is a way to get the actual event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want an event object you'll need to create a custom `View`. Here is an example of something I used in my App:

```
App.ProductsGridSortButtonView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'a',
  classNames: ['productsSortButton'],
  attributeBindings: ['data-sort','data-sort-type'],
  click: function(e){
    this.get('parentView').sortProducts(e);
  }
});
```

and in the template:

```
{{#view App.ProductsGridSortButtonView data-sort="price" data-sort-type="number"}}
```

Comment: I guess that would work....but lets be honest, this is a terrible solution. I'm starting to question the direction Ember is taking with pre4. The new way of setting up routers is great, but so many other things have just been broken.

Comment: I can see your point.. and it can take time to move from pre1 to the latest version... though this is a core concept and will make for better code, _a `View` is where you handle user interaction/event_ the guide is being updated on this I think [see here](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/core-concepts/#toc_views)